# How to align images and text in an alternating style

Tags: html, css, mobile, format

I'm trying to create an alternating About Us section where one member has their photo to the left and description on the right.  The next member would have their description on the left and then their image to the right.

I tried using another template for the setup, but it doesn't line up quite well.  The images that are aligned on the left are fine, but the text of the descriptions are a bit too close.  The images that are aligned to the right don't go all the way to the end of the border.  They float in the right-side area, but they don't take up the full width of the section.

Additionally, I'm trying to get it to format nicely on mobile where everything is centered (centered image with their descriptions following after).  Right now, the descriptions look a bit squished in the center with big margins taking up space.  Also, the images aligned to the right won't center correctly.

I don't think this is the best way to go about it, but any advice or guidance is appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css>
<link href=https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,700,900|Ubuntu:400,500,700 rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 640px){ /*Desktop*/
img, img2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    float: center;
}
.container {
    padding: 2px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    
}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 640px){ /*Desktop*/
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
h4 {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
}

img {
    float: left;
    -webkit-float: left;
    padding: 30px;
    clear: both;
}
img2 {
    float: right;
    -webkit-float: right;
    padding: 30px;
    clear: both;
    
}
.container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 57px;
    
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #5e5c5c;
    text-align: center;

}
h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #5e5c5c;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
li {
    margin: 10px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

        <!-----#Michael----->
<div class='container'>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9QsRxd2q/Michael.png" alt="Michael"/ width="25%" height="25%">
        </div>  
    <div>
    <ul>
    <h1><br /><b>Michael Schlaefer, CEO</b></h1>
    <h4><li>Owner of Global Development Contractors, LLC; Plymouth Industries, LLC; Liberty Stone & Aggregates - Clinton Quarry, LLC; Vision Development Group, LLC; and Green Earth Container Service, LLC.</li>
    <li>Over 40 years of experience in site work; demolition; remediation; trucking material management, facility operations, complex brownfield and landfill redevelopment projects.</li>
    <li>Board member – Tewksbury Environmental Commission</li></h4>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-----#Jen----->
<div class='container'>
        <div>
            <img2><img src=https://i.postimg.cc/nhX9YdyJ/Jen.png alt="Jen"/ width="60%" height="60%"></img2>
        </div>  
    <div>
    <ul>
    <h1><br /><br /><b>Jennifer D. Kraft, COO</b></h1>
    <h4><li>In-house counsel for Global Development Contractors, LLC with extensive experience with material management, operations, site development and compliance with environment regulations.</li>
    <li>Chair – Tewksbury Board of Health</li>
    <li>Member – Professional Women in Construction (PWC)</li></h4>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container:nth-of-type(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Review CSS flexbox for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Currell/g7t6mu2j/

Comment: To add to this, you can also incorporate "align-items: center;" to the .container to mimic the vertical-align:middle content/image alignment behavior that you can achieve with inline-blocks.